# How to use the Microsoft Linker /Export parameter

Tags: dll, linker, export

I would like to export functions from my object files manually with the Microsoft Linker.
It works fine when I use the parameter for every function like this:

```
/Export:ExportedFunction1$qqsv /Export:ExportedFunction2$qqsv and so on...
```

The linker then automatically assigns the ords properly. However in the export table the actuall export name is "`ExportedFunction1$qqsv/ExportedFunction2$qqsv/etc..`"
I tried the parameter doing like this:

```
/Export:ExportedFunction1$qqsv,1,ExportedFunction1 /Export:ExportedFunction2$qqsv,2,ExportedFunction2
```

But I think I'm using the parameters wrong?! How do I use the /Export parameter properly to assign my own names for the exports?

PS.:
I'm using Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 7.00.9210

Comment: Have you read docs at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k30y2k5.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sorry, it looks I missed the problem.. Do you want to rename an exported function or change the ordinal?

Comment: Rename the exported function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample solution with a DEF file.

**DLL-project:**

**CppLib.h:**

```
#ifdef CPPLIB_EXPORTS
#define CPPLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CPPLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

CPPLIB_API double MyFunction1(double);
```

**CppLib.cpp:**

```
CPPLIB_API double MyFunction1(double dd)
{
    return dd;
}
```

**CppLib.def:**

```
LIBRARY

EXPORTS
MySuperFunction=MyFunction1 @1
```

Build DLL.

**If we run dumpbin on CppLib.DLL, we'll get:**

```
...
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          2    0 0001101E ?MyFunction1@@YANN@Z = @ILT+25(?MyFunction1@@YANN@Z)
          1    1 0001101E MySuperFunction = @ILT+25(?MyFunction1@@YANN@Z)
...
```

---

**Console Application that uses CppLib.dll:**

```
#include "CppLib.h"

#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef double(*MY_SUPER_FUNC)(double);

    HMODULE hm = LoadLibraryW(L"CppLib.dll");
    MY_SUPER_FUNC fn1 = (MY_SUPER_FUNC)GetProcAddress(hm, "MySuperFunction"); // find by name
    MY_SUPER_FUNC fn2 = (MY_SUPER_FUNC)GetProcAddress(hm, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(1)); // find by ordinal

    std::cout << fn1(34.5) << std::endl; // prints 34.5
    std::cout << fn2(12.3) << std::endl; // prints 12.3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thats what I was looking for! Thank you very much! It was simply `MySuperFunction=MyFunction1 @1`

Comment: @Benjamin Weiss You're welcome! You can omit setting ordinal _@1_ if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:ExportedFunction1$qqsv=_YouMangledFunction1@@")
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:ExportedFunction2$qqsv=_YouMangledFunction2@@")
```

Comment: Is this for the .def file?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you get that kind of contol with the /Export command-line switch, but you can do it with a .DEF file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports

Comment: I tried to make a .def file, but I had no success. If you have an easy example, that would be nice.